# Hiding and Showing A drop down list with Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, devexpress

I use javascript to hide and show dev express combo box control.

In the page load I have the following  code to hide the control:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    document.getElementById('StateDropDown').style.display = 'none';
}
```

When the country is set as United States, then I show the combo box with US States.

```
if(s.GetText() == 'UNITED STATES') {
    document.getElementById('StateTextBox').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('StateDropDown').style.display = 'block';
}
else {
    document.getElementById('StateDropDown').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('StateTextBox').style.display = 'block';
}
e.processOnServer = false;
```

The problem is the size of the drop down when it's shown.
Even though I set Country Combo Box and State Combo Box to be the same size, State Combo Box is shorter when it is shown on the screen. This happens in Internet Explorer. Chrome renders correctly.

Anyone knows why IE behaves like that?

Comment: are you using compatibility view?

Comment: Yes, it is Compatibility view. I changed it to IE9 and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DevExpress controls, suggest the following approach subscribe to events :

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {});
```

or

```
ASPxClientUtils.AttachEventToElement("load", function() {});
```